# Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException:

Tags: spring-boot

AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext,txid=,subtxnbr=,sid=,user=,bizpn=,cnsmr=,reqid=,cnsmr=,Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
2022-05-11T08:25:05.879-04:00,severity=INFO,thread=main,logger=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.logging.ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener,txid=,subtxnbr=,sid=,user=,bizpn=,cnsmr=,reqid=,cnsmr=,

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2022-05-11T08:25:05.929-04:00,severity=ERROR,thread=main,logger=org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication,txid=,subtxnbr=,sid=,user=,bizpn=,cnsmr=,reqid=,cnsmr=,Application run failed
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:163) ~[spring-boot-2.5.13.jar!/:2.5.13]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:577) ~[spring-context-5.3.19.jar!/:5.3.19]
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145) ~[spring-boot-2.5.13.jar!/:2.5.13]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775) ~[spring-boot-2.5.13.jar!/:2.5.13]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:448) ~[spring-boot-2.5.13.jar!/:2.5.13]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:339) ~[spring-boot-2.5.13.jar!/:2.5.13]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1365) ~[spring-boot-2.5.13.jar!/:2.5.13]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1354) ~[spring-boot-2.5.13.jar!/:2.5.13]
at com.paychex.register.SsoregisterApplication.main(SsoregisterApplication.java:51) ~[classes!/:develop-202205110822]
at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:?]
at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:?]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[?:?]
at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49) ~[register-svc.jar:develop-202205110822]
at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:108) ~[register-svc.jar:develop-202205110822]
at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58) ~[register-svc.jar:develop-202205110822]
at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:88) ~[register-svc.jar:develop-202205110822]
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:142) ~[spring-boot-2.5.13.jar!/:2.5.13]
at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.(TomcatWebServer.java:104) ~[spring-boot-2.5.13.jar!/:2.5.13]
at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getTomcatWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:456) ~[spring-boot-2.5.13.jar!/:2.5.13]
at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:204) ~[spring-boot-2.5.13.jar!/:2.5.13]
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:182) ~[spring-boot-2.5.13.jar!/:2.5.13]
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:160) ~[spring-boot-2.5.13.jar!/:2.5.13]
... 16 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'servletEndpointRegistrar' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/endpoint/web/ServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration$WebMvcServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.ServletEndpointRegistrar]: Factory method 'servletEndpointRegistrar' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Invalid extension 'infoWebEndpointExtension': no endpoint found with id 'info'
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:658) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar!/:5.3.19]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:638) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar!/:5.3.19]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1352) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar!/:5.3.19]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1195) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar!/:5.3.19]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar!/:5.3.19]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar!/:5.3.19]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar!/:5.3.19]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar!/:5.3.19]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar!/:5.3.19]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:213) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar!/:5.3.19]
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.getOrderedBeansOfType(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:212) ~[spring-boot-2.5.13.jar!/:2.5.13]
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.getOrderedBeansOfType(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:203) ~[spring-boot-2.5.13.jar!/:2.5.13]
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.addServletContextInitializerBeans(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:97) ~[spring-boot-2.5.13.jar!/:2.5.13]
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:86) ~[spring-boot-2.5.13.jar!/:2.5.13]
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.getServletContextInitializerBeans(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:260) ~[spring-boot-2.5.13.jar!/:2.5.13]
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.selfInitialize(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:234) ~[spring-boot-2.5.13.jar!/:2.5.13]
at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatStarter.onStartup(TomcatStarter.java:53) ~[spring-boot-2.5.13.jar!/:2.5.13]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5219) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar!/:?]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar!/:?]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1396) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar!/:?]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1386) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar!/:?]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[?:?]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar!/:?]
at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140) ~[?:?]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:919) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar!/:?]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:835) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar!/:?]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar!/:?]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1396) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar!/:?]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1386) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar!/:?]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[?:?]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar!/:?]
at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140) ~[?:?]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:919) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar!/:?]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:263) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar!/:?]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar!/:?]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:432) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar!/:?]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar!/:?]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:927) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar!/:?]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar!/:?]
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:486) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar!/:?]
at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:123) ~[spring-boot-2.5.13.jar!/:2.5.13]
at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.(TomcatWebServer.java:104) ~[spring-boot-2.5.13.jar!/:2.5.13]
at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getTomcatWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:456) ~[spring-boot-2.5.13.jar!/:2.5.13]
at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:204) ~[spring-boot-2.5.13.jar!/:2.5.13]
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:182) ~[spring-boot-2.5.13.jar!/:2.5.13]
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:160) ~[spring-boot-2.5.13.jar!/:2.5.13]
... 16 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.ServletEndpointRegistrar]: Factory method 'servletEndpointRegistrar' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Invalid extension 'infoWebEndpointExtension': no endpoint found with id 'info'
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar!/:5.3.19]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:653) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar!/:5.3.19]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:638) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar!/:5.3.19]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1352) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar!/:5.3.19]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1195) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar!/:5.3.19]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar!/:5.3.19]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar!/:5.3.19]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar!/:5.3.19]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar!/:5.3.19]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar!/:5.3.19]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:213) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar!/:5.3.19]
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.getOrderedBeansOfType(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:212) ~[spring-boot-2.5.13.jar!/:2.5.13]
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.getOrderedBeansOfType(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:203) ~[spring-boot-2.5.13.jar!/:2.5.13]
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.addServletContextInitializerBeans(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:97) ~[spring-boot-2.5.13.jar!/:2.5.13]
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:86) ~[spring-boot-2.5.13.jar!/:2.5.13]
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.getServletContextInitializerBeans(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:260) ~[spring-boot-2.5.13.jar!/:2.5.13]
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.selfInitialize(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:234) ~[spring-boot-2.5.13.jar!/:2.5.13]
at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatStarter.onStartup(TomcatStarter.java:53) ~[spring-boot-2.5.13.jar!/:2.5.13]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5219) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar!/:?]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar!/:?]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1396) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar!/:?]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1386) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar!/:?]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[?:?]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar!/:?]
at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140) ~[?:?]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:919) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar!/:?]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:835) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar!/:?]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar!/:?]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1396) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar!/:?]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1386) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar!/:?]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[?:?]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar!/:?]
at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140) ~[?:?]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:919) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar!/:?]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:263) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar!/:?]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar!/:?]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:432) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar!/:?]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar!/:?]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:927) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar!/:?]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar!/:?]
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:486) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar!/:?]
at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:123) ~[spring-boot-2.5.13.jar!/:2.5.13]
at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.(TomcatWebServer.java:104) ~[spring-boot-2.5.13.jar!/:2.5.13]
at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getTomcatWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:456) ~[spring-boot-2.5.13.jar!/:2.5.13]
at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:204) ~[spring-boot-2.5.13.jar!/:2.5.13]
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:182) ~[spring-boot-2.5.13.jar!/:2.5.13]
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:160) ~[spring-boot-2.5.13.jar!/:2.5.13]
... 16 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Invalid extension 'infoWebEndpointExtension': no endpoint found with id 'info'
at org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:97) ~[spring-core-5.3.19.jar!/:5.3.19]
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.annotation.EndpointDiscoverer.addExtensionBeans(EndpointDiscoverer.java:157) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.5.13.jar!/:2.5.13]
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.annotation.EndpointDiscoverer.discoverEndpoints(EndpointDiscoverer.java:124) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.5.13.jar!/:2.5.13]
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.annotation.EndpointDiscoverer.getEndpoints(EndpointDiscoverer.java:117) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.5.13.jar!/:2.5.13]
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.endpoint.web.ServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration$WebMvcServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration.servletEndpointRegistrar(ServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration.java:65) ~[spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure-2.5.13.jar!/:2.5.13]
at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:?]
at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:?]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[?:?]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar!/:5.3.19]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:653) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar!/:5.3.19]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:638) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar!/:5.3.19]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1352) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar!/:5.3.19]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1195) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar!/:5.3.19]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar!/:5.3.19]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar!/:5.3.19]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar!/:5.3.19]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar!/:5.3.19]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar!/:5.3.19]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:213) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar!/:5.3.19]
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.getOrderedBeansOfType(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:212) ~[spring-boot-2.5.13.jar!/:2.5.13]
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.getOrderedBeansOfType(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:203) ~[spring-boot-2.5.13.jar!/:2.5.13]
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.addServletContextInitializerBeans(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:97) ~[spring-boot-2.5.13.jar!/:2.5.13]
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:86) ~[spring-boot-2.5.13.jar!/:2.5.13]
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.getServletContextInitializerBeans(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:260) ~[spring-boot-2.5.13.jar!/:2.5.13]
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.selfInitialize(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:234) ~[spring-boot-2.5.13.jar!/:2.5.13]
at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatStarter.onStartup(TomcatStarter.java:53) ~[spring-boot-2.5.13.jar!/:2.5.13]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5219) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar!/:?]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar!/:?]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1396) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar!/:?]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1386) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar!/:?]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[?:?]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar!/:?]
at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140) ~[?:?]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:919) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar!/:?]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:835) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar!/:?]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar!/:?]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1396) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar!/:?]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1386) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar!/:?]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[?:?]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar!/:?]
at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140) ~[?:?]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:919) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar!/:?]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:263) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar!/:?]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar!/:?]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:432) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar!/:?]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar!/:?]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:927) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar!/:?]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar!/:?]
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:486) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar!/:?]
at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:123) ~[spring-boot-2.5.13.jar!/:2.5.13]
at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.(TomcatWebServer.java:104) ~[spring-boot-2.5.13.jar!/:2.5.13]
at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getTomcatWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:456) ~[spring-boot-2.5.13.jar!/:2.5.13]
at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:204) ~[spring-boot-2.5.13.jar!/:2.5.13]
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:182) ~[spring-boot-2.5.13.jar!/:2.5.13]
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:160) ~[spring-boot-2.5.13.jar!/:2.5.13]
... 16 more

Comment: If you could put any other information apart from dumping the error log it would be more helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The stacktrace suggests that your application can not resolve actuator's `/info` endpoint.  I see you are using `spring-boot-2.5.13`.  [Starting in spring boot 2.5.0](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.5-Release-Notes#secure-info-endpoint), in order to expose actuator's `/info` endpoint, you need to enable it through your application properties by adding the equivalent of `management.endpoints.web.​exposure.include: 'info'`

Here is the [acutator section of the official spring boot documentation for 2.5.13](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.5.13/reference/html/actuator.html#actuator.endpoints.enabling).